# Remove invalid characters from String when parsing XML in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I've been googling around and reading on SO, but nothing worked. I have a problem with characters in an XML feed. I save the value of each tag in a String, but when `&#13;` occurs, it just stops. I only get the 4-5 first words in the tag or so.

So can anyone please help me with a method that can remove it? Or can it be that the text in the tags in the XML feed are too long for a String?

Thanks!

Sample code:

```
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */ 
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        sitesList.setTitle(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        sitesList.setId(currentValue);
    else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
        sitesList.setDescription(currentValue);
}
```

The text in the description tag is quite long, but I only get the first five words before the `&#13;` characters starts coming.

Comment: Could you show relevant parts of your code, and what kind of invalid characters you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a SAXparser to parse the XML-String.

The `characters()`-method can be called multiple times when only reading one XML-element. This happens when it finds something like `<desc>blabla bla & # 39; bla bla la.</desc>`.

The solution is to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and append the readed characters in the `characters()`-method and then reset the `StringBuilder` in the `endElement()`-method:

```
private class Handler extends DefaultHandler{

    private StringBuilder temp_val;

    public Handler(){
        this.temp_val = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
        temp_val.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
        System.out.println("Output: "+temp_val.toString());
        // ... Do your stuff
        temp_val.setLength(0); // Reset the StringBuilder
    }

}
```

---

The above code works for me, given this XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<test>This is some &#13; example-text.</test>
```

The output is:

> Output: This is some 
>    example-text.

Comment: so when I set the values I should use temp_val.toString() ?

Comment: set your values in the `endElement()`-method and at it's end, you reset the `StringBuilder`. And please be more specific about "does not work".

Comment: You mean set the values, as in temp_val.toString() ? I did exactly that, and I still don't get all of the text from my description tag. It stops when it hits the characters I complained about in my post.

Comment: Can it have something to do with the encoding of the XML? Mine is UTF-8

Comment: I did exactly like you did in your post, and it won't add whatever text that is after the annoying characters.

Comment: For me it also works when i use UTF-8 as the encoding. Have you tried using a [`XmlPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)? If you use `next()` to process the file, the parser should process the entity's.